# in the Discussion or in *Discussion* or

Tags: articles, definite-article, zero-article

In a scientific journal paper, when something is briefly discussed in one section (e.g., Introduction) and want to say it is further discussed in the discussion section (which is usually the last section of the main text), which one is more appropriate? Or are there other standards? Discussion section here is just an example and could be any other section (e.g., Materials and Methods).

> ... is further discussed in the Discussion
>
> ... is further discussed in *Discussion*

Similarly,

> (See *Discussion* for details)
>
> (See the Discussion for details)

Comment: So you mean that "*Discussion*" is the name of a chapter in your paper? If that's the case, don't use the article.

Comment: @Catija Yes, it is a section of a paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the title of a section the way you are, you do not need the article.

> (see *Methods* for details)

Think about it this way:

Imagine you're talking about a book... I'll use *Harry Potter*... you wouldn't say:

> Read **the** *Harry Potter* for the full story.

**The** is unnecessary:

> Read *Harry Potter* for the full story.

You might also say (good for variety):

> Read **the book** called *Harry Potter* for the full story.

So, you could similarly say:

> See the section called/labeled/titled *Methods* for details.